# Rotating Bitmaps on canvas seems chopped

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, rotation

I am trying to rotate some bitmaps(7 bitmaps) together on canvas. They are all of different sizes. I am using following code to rotate these bitmaps:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setTranslate(x, y);
matrix.postRotate(rotateAngle,centerX, centerY);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
```

Bitmaps are rotating as desired. The problem I am having is the bitmaps are not rotating smooth on some devices. They are working fine on small sized devices but as the screen size is increasing, rotation is being chopped.

Also, I have noticed that rotating 2-3 bitmaps is giving smooth rotation but when I am trying to rotate all of them together, rotation is being chopped. What should I do to resolve this? Thanks all in advance.

I have also tried canvas.rotate method but still the issue remains.

Comment: Could you illustrate 'chopped' ?

Comment: rotation is not smooth...bitmaps are spinning like "second" hand of a clock..

Comment: there is a lapse between each rotation